# Failing to write async recursive iteration function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursion method to retrieve the parent of a object (and that parent etc). This in itself isn't a problem but the calls are async which result in the following error:

> The body of '.....Recursive(string)' cannot be an iterator block because 'Task<IEnumerable>' is not an iterator interface type [...]csharp(CS1624)

The code:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Recursive(string objectId)
{
    var result = await GetParent(objectId);
    if (result?.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return result;
        await Recursive(objectId);
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetParent(string objectId)
{
    await Task.Run(() => { return $"{objectId}/parent"; });
}
```

I have also tried `IAsyncEnumerable` but that resulted in the folllowing error:

> 'IAsyncEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [...]csharp(CS1061)

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Recursive(string objectId)
{
    var result = await GetParent(objectId);
    if (result?.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return result;
        await Recursive(objectId);
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetParent(string objectId)
{
    await Task.Run(() => { return $"{objectId}/parent"; });
}
```

I'm going to write a while loop to get this to work. But I'm interested if this is possible at all.

Update 2:
Ok, I think I got it. Thanks guys.

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Recursive(string objectId)
{
    var result = await GetParent(objectId);
    if (result?.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return result;
        await foreach (var r2 in Recursive(objectId))
        {
            yield return r2;
        }
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetParent(string objectId)
{
    await Task.Run(() => { return $"{objectId}/parent"; });
}
```

Comment: The type `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` promises that the consumer may have to wait a bit, but once the waiting is over, the consumer will be able to fetch all elements without delay. Your method doesn't do that: after it yields a result, there's a potential further delay. You do want `IAsyncEnumerable`, which allows a delay between successive elements. However, you haven't given us any information on "that resulted in more problems", so it's hard to help

Comment: The error is clear - you can't use `yield` unless the method returns `IEnumerable` or `IAsyncEnumerable.` *This* implementation won't work. What did you try with `IAsyncEnumerable` ?  PS what you wrote wouldn't work with `IEnumerable` either. You can't just return an `IEnumerable` from inside an iterator

Comment: Try to create a recursive method that works with `IEnumerable` first, before converting it to use `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: I'm not sure if async is relevant, you cannot write an recursive iterative function the way you attempt to do, at least if I understand the intent correctly. Iterator blocks and recursion do not mix very well. It is probably better to just write an iterative solution if possible or make a recursive solution with a callback for each element. An example that demonstrates the actual problem would probably be helpful.

Comment: One moment, I will add IAsyncEnumerable attempt..

Comment: @RalfdeKleine what you wrote won't work even with `IEnumerable`. What are you trying to do? Once you get your code to work with  `IEnumerable` it will work with `IAsyncEnumerable` as well

Comment: The main problem with your `IAsyncEnumerable` one is that you need to use `await foreach` to loop over it. You're not yielding any of the results which are returned by the recursive calls to `Recursive`, in any of your implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current code wouldn't compile even if it was synchronous, and the result was `IEnumerable<string>`. The results of `Recursive` are never returned. It's not possible to just return an `IEnumerable` from an iterator either.

This code would work. Whether it does anything useful is another matter :

```
private IEnumerable<string> Recursive(string objectId)
{
    var result = GetParent(objectId);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        yield return result;
        foreach(var r in Recursive(result))
        {
            yield return r;
        }
    }
}

private string GetParent(string objectId)
{
    return $"{objectId}/parent";
    
}
```

Getting it to work asynchronously only needs changing to `IAsyncEnumerable` and using `await`:

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Recursive(string objectId)
{
    var result = await GetParent(objectId);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        yield return result;
        await foreach(var r in Recursive(result))
        {
            yield return r;
        }
    }
}

private  Task<string> GetParent(string objectId)
{
    return Task.FromResult($"{objectId}/parent");
}
```

Comment: While this is probably what was asked for, assuming the iteration is finite, it should result in n iterator objects created, and n^2 `MoveNext` method calls. I.e. not ideal.

Comment: @JonasH for doing what? We have no idea what the actual problem is. The code itself only appends `/parent` to the original string, something a simple loop would do and a `previous +="/parent"`. If we knew what the actual problem is we could come up with far better solutions

Comment: Some insight into the usecase. I have a (SAP) Organisation which has a parent (this is finite). I need to assemble a hierchical list from said organisation until I found the root parent. The max depth is 5 or 6 steps deep.

Comment: I agree that this is probably what was asked for. But It is usually a good idea to point out if things are a poor idea. There are few, if any, cases I can think of where iterating over the result of a recursive function, in that same function, is the best way to solve things.